# The type or namespace 'App' does not exist in the current namespace

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am having an issue with a newly made Xamarin.Forms app in Visual Studio 2015.  I added the Droid/iOS projects to the solution and it is giving me a build error saying...

`The type or namespace 'App' does not exist in the current namespace`

Here is an example of where the two errors are.

Droid project:

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
                LoadApplication (new MyApp.App ());
                //Error on the above line at MyApp.App ()
            }
        }
}
```

iOS project:

```
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
            LoadApplication (new MyApp.App ());
            //Error on above line in MyApp.App ()
            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution was just made and no coding done yet, could this be an issue with VS2015?

Comment: do your two platform projects have a reference to the shared Forms PCL project?  That is where the App class lives by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an issue that still exists.  While this may not have been the solution back in July, this is the working solution for 3/31/16.

- Clean the solution
- Build the PCL
- Remove the PCL reference from the affected project(s)
- Re-add the PCL reference
- Build

This also happens sometimes after opening a XAML file and switching back to a C# file in the PCL project.

Comment: I can confirm that the described workaround is working as at the time of writing.

Comment: Still the case in VS2017. Still a working solution. Thank you.

Comment: The issue still occurs in Visual Studio 2019 Preview with brand-new Xamarin applications, but I can confirm that this solution works. Has anyone reported it as a bug to Microsoft yet?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the Forms PCL project, it will do it by default when you create the project unless you create each project individually. Just Right Click on the MyApp.Droid project -> Add Reference -> Solution -> Check MyApp(?!?!)

Comment: This still works now in the year 2018, and in Visual Studio 2017, without doing any of the more tedious solutions above. Thanks!

Comment: Very useful answer. Surprising that Xamarin is broken out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @silencedmessage helped me.

Though I would like to add that I noticed that all my Xamarin projects did not even have a PCL reference to start with. I started with a blank Xamarin Forms XAML project template for all possible targets and I did not even bother checking the reference to the PCL, before I read this answer.

So long story short: Even from a blank official template you should still check that the PCL reference is added to all projects. Weird stuff.

Comment: I too found this to be true. Using VS 2015 Enterprise Update 2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a WPF app. I fixed it by opening the project properties, copying the assembly name to default namespace, saving the file, and doing the same thing the other way around.
These values already were the same, but for some reason it make visual studio add alot to the project file.
These were added the the first PropertyGroup (containing the TargetFrameworkVersion):

```
<PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
<Install>true</Install>
<InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
<UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
<UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
<UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
<UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
<UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
<UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
<MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
<ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
<IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
<UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
<BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
```

All "Page" tags are regrouped in a new ItemGroup, separate from the "Compile" tags.

Also, this entire ItemGroup was added:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
```