# Shared Xamarin.Forms - The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making my way through [this](https://elearning.xamarin.com/forms/xam120/) Xamarin.Forms tutorial. I built a Shared project according to the instructions, but I'm getting an error on a file that I was given to download, that is supposed to let my app access the dialing function on Android.

This is the full error I'm getting:

```
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace 'Phoneword.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   Phoneword.Android
```

I found a few similar-sounding errors online, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347788/3739453), but none of the solutions worked for me. The general trend seemed to be that the App class lives in the Shared project, so a broken reference might be causing the problem, but I removed the Android reference to the Shared project, and a bunch of other errors came up, and then I re-added it, and all the errors but the "App" one went away. So I don't think it's a reference issue.

**PhoneDialer.Droid.cs** (I marked the line with the error)

```
using Android.Content;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Telephony;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Phoneword.Android;

using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhoneDialer))]

namespace Phoneword.Android
{
    public class PhoneDialer : IDialer
    {
        public Task<bool> DialAsync(string number)
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context; //<=ERROR
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When I change the line to `Phoneword.App.Application.Context`, "App" doesn't throw any error, but then I get another error saying that "Application" doesn't exist.

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

I uploaded the solution to github so all my code is visible: https://github.com/joeymorano/Phoneword

Comment: If you can upload project to Github, may be people can give help lot easy

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga Good idea, I added a link to Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cheeky Error....

Change your current namespace `namespace Phoneword.Android` to `namespace Phoneword.Droid`, everything will work

When you have namespace called `namespace Phoneword.Android` and try to access `Android.App.Application.Context`, `Android.` refer as your current project... not the android native library

[image]

Comment: So then I should also change the line "using Phoneword.Android;" to "using Phoneword.Droid;"?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the problem. Thanks so much! Would you recommend renaming the whole project to Phoneword.Droid?