# Error on LoadApplication in Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, portable-class-library

I created a new `Xamarin Forms PCL` solution, and in debug mode I checked the `Enable ProGuard` option and I selected `Linking` comboxbox to `Sdk and User Assemblies`.
Now I run my application on android, after that it shows me an error in MainActivity.cs class and on line

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I do that because of to decrease the size of my release app, and I have to change the release mode to debug in order to check what happened.

Comment: I assume you are using Xamarin Forms? Please post the line of code that is throwing the error. I think your issue is that you need to change it to `LoadApplication(new PCLNameHere.App())`

Comment: I tried that , but it falls into error on line LoadApplication(new App()); 
The important point is , when i changed Linking option to none and unchecked ProGuard option , my applicatrion run successfully.
I need those options to decrease my final .apk file

Comment: What does the rest of the stacktrace say?

Comment: Linking against SDK assemblies only isn't enough?

Comment: @hvaughan3 The value of my Environment.StackTrace is :
  at System.Environment.get_StackTrace () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception ) [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException (System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Object.d09f62bf-1e4f-438b-810e-1b2febfe5330 (System.IntPtr , System.IntPtr , System.IntPtr ) [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0

Comment: @hichame.yessou , I'm using a lot of components in my project and if i select that option my app doesn't lunch

Comment: @AmirHosseinKhajegan You might want to just try excluding all of your component/library assemblies from being linked to see if that initially fixes the issue. Then remove them one-by-on from the exclusion list to see which ones is causing the issue. To exclude see this: [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/#Skipping_Assemblies) and [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip)

Comment: @hvaughan3 , Next my try was this , i created a new project without any component and do that , the result was that same error .
Please create a new Xamarin Forms PCL app and if you test it , you can see that error . i do that in some different PC

Answer (score 4):

As per: [The type or namespace 'App' does not exist in the current namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666284/the-type-or-namespace-app-does-not-exist-in-the-current-namespace/36347788#36347788)

Clean the solution
Build the PCL
Remove the PCL reference from the affected project(s)
Re-add the PCL reference
Build

I tried this solution and it works.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at your App.xaml.cs file.
If you have a "InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context error", this is likely caused by a known VS bug.

### Solution:

- Right click on App.xaml.cs and select Properties.
- Change the Build Action to "Content".
- Apply.
- Change Build Action back to C# Compiler.
- Clean Solution.
- Build and Deploy.